# Edit text using Python and curses Textbox widget?

Tags: python, ncurses

Has anybody got a working example of using the curses.textpad.Textbox widget to edit existing text? This is, of course, in a Linux terminal (e.g. xterm).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found that the `Edit` widget in the [urwid](http://urwid.org) package is sufficient for my needs. This is not the Textpad widget, but something different. The urwid package is overall nicer, anyway. However, it's still not pain-free.  The `Edit` widget does allow inserting text, but not overwriting (toggled with Ins key), but that's not a big deal.

Comment: *The urwid package is overall nicer.* :) is also my up to now experience.

Answer (score 9):

Found this there is several minutes

```
import curses
import curses.textpad

stdscr = curses.initscr()
# don't echo key strokes on the screen
curses.noecho()
# read keystrokes instantly, without waiting for enter to ne pressed
curses.cbreak()
# enable keypad mode
stdscr.keypad(1)
stdscr.clear()
stdscr.refresh()
win = curses.newwin(5, 60, 5, 10)
tb = curses.textpad.Textbox(win)
text = tb.edit()
curses.beep()
win.addstr(4,1,text.encode('utf_8'))
```

I also made a function to make a textbox:

```
def maketextbox(h,w,y,x,value="",deco=None,underlineChr=curses.ACS_HLINE,textColorpair=0,decoColorpair=0):
    nw = curses.newwin(h,w,y,x)
    txtbox = curses.textpad.Textbox(nw)
    if deco=="frame":
        screen.attron(decoColorpair)
        curses.textpad.rectangle(screen,y-1,x-1,y+h,x+w)
        screen.attroff(decoColorpair)
    elif deco=="underline":
        screen.hline(y+1,x,underlineChr,w,decoColorpair)

    nw.addstr(0,0,value,textColorpair)
    nw.attron(textColorpair)
    screen.refresh()
    return txtbox
```

To use it just do:

```
foo = maketextbox(1,40, 10,20,"foo",deco="underline",textColorpair=curses.color_pair(0),decoColorpair=curses.color_pair(1))
text = foo.edit()
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort. I did try the Textbox already. But its editing is just too basic. You can't even insert text. I was hoping to find something more like nano, but embeddable in an app.

Comment: I had to change the last two lines to: `stdscr.addstr(1,1,text)  stdscr.refresh()` to get it working. After entering text in the textpad I had to press Ctrl-G to submit it.

Comment: Also, it says that `curses.ACS_HLINE` is not defined

Answer (score 6):

`textpad.Textbox(win, insert_mode=True)` provides basic insert support. Backspace needs to be added though.

Answer (score 3):

The initial code didn't work, decided to have a hack at it, this works on insert mode and then when you press Ctrl-G display's the text at the right position.

```python
import curses
import curses.textpad

def main(stdscr):
    stdscr.clear()
    stdscr.refresh()
    win = curses.newwin(5, 60, 5, 10)

    tb = curses.textpad.Textbox(win, insert_mode=True)
    text = tb.edit()
    curses.flash()
    win.clear()
    win.addstr(0, 0, text.encode('utf-8'))
    win.refresh()
    win.getch()

curses.wrapper(main)
```