# Can I use Python's curses and cmd libraries together?

Tags: python, cmd, curses

In Python, I'd like to write a terminal program using both cmd and curses together, ie. use cmd to accept and decode full input lines, but position the output with curses.

Mashing together examples of both curses and cmd like this :

```
import curses 
import cmd

class HelloWorld(cmd.Cmd):
    """Simple command processor example."""

    def do_greet(self, line):
        screen.clear()
        screen.addstr(1,1,"hello "+line)
        screen.addstr(0,1,">")
        screen.refresh()

    def do_q(self, line):
        curses.endwin()
        return True

if __name__ == '__main__':
    screen = curses.initscr()   
    HelloWorld().cmdloop()
```

I find that I'm not seeing anything when I type. curses is presumably waiting for a refresh before displaying anything on the screen. I could switch to using getch() but then I'd lose the value of cmd.

Is there a way to make these work together?

Comment: considering these are two totally different worlds of languages as python is I think a object based program and batch is completely for windows control I have not seen any way to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question seems to be very old... But it attracted enough of attention so i thought to leave my answer behind.. You can check out the site [here](https://gist.github.com/interstar/3005137) and clear your doubts..

Update : this answer links to the gist from the original questioner. Just to save someone having to follow the link ... here's the code in full :

```
#!/usr/bin/env python 
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*- 

import curses 
import curses.textpad
import cmd

def maketextbox(h,w,y,x,value="",deco=None,textColorpair=0,decoColorpair=0):
    # thanks to http://stackoverflow.com/a/5326195/8482 for this
    nw = curses.newwin(h,w,y,x)
    txtbox = curses.textpad.Textbox(nw,insert_mode=True)
    if deco=="frame":
        screen.attron(decoColorpair)
        curses.textpad.rectangle(screen,y-1,x-1,y+h,x+w)
        screen.attroff(decoColorpair)
    elif deco=="underline":
        screen.hline(y+1,x,underlineChr,w,decoColorpair)

    nw.addstr(0,0,value,textColorpair)
    nw.attron(textColorpair)
    screen.refresh()
    return nw,txtbox

class Commands(cmd.Cmd):
    """Simple command processor example."""
        
    def __init__(self):
        cmd.Cmd.__init__(self)
        self.prompt = "> "
        self.intro  = "Welcome to console!"  ## defaults to None
    
    def do_greet(self, line):
        self.write("hello "+line)

    def default(self,line) :
        self.write("Don't understand '" + line + "'")

    def do_quit(self, line):
        curses.endwin()
        return True

    def write(self,text) :
        screen.clear()
        textwin.clear()
        screen.addstr(3,0,text)
        screen.refresh()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    screen = curses.initscr()   
    curses.noecho()
    textwin,textbox = maketextbox(1,40, 1,1,"")
    flag = False
    while not flag :
        text = textbox.edit()
    curses.beep()
    flag = Commands().onecmd(text)
```

Comment: You should link to external resources for your **own** code. Links can go down. At least give a minimal description of what your answer is about.

Comment: Yeah.. agreed, but the question isn't bit too old and even after getting much views nobody got time for even comments... so i thought it could help 

Comment: Well. A) I guess you are interested in being upvoted ... but upvotes come for delivered quality ;-) B) keep in mind: in the end, our answers are intended to *help* as many folks as possible ... simply strive to give "your best" ... all the time.

Comment: He he ... that's actually MY (as the original questioner) example of how I ended up doing this. :-D ... accepting the answer for chutzpah of finding and linking it ... my bad for not updating the answer here.

Comment: This code doesn't run (indent errors) and if you modify it to get it running it doesn't really function as a "command line inside curses" in any way -  Have you tried to use it? You have to type ^G to send the line; you can't use Enter and doing so repeatedly munges what you wrote previously and previous output.