# Having inputs between text/strings - Python

Tags: python, string, text, python-3.x, input

I am looking for a way to have a user input entered between two strings. Is there an easy way to do this?

For example;

```
input("text blah blah" The users input appears here " more text is here")
```

so when the program is running it would look like this;

> text blah blah more text here

and the user can input the text between ***'blah'*** and ***'more'***.

Comment: it would imply some kind of control over the terminal, which you can't achieve using simply input.

Comment: You might be interested in the [`curses` module](http://docs.python.org/3.1/howto/curses.html) if you want to build complicated interfaces.  [This SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4581441/edit-text-using-python-and-curses-textbox-widget) might be relevant.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this but you need to use the input first.

```
print(f"text blah blah {input()} more text is here")
```

Comment: if you run the code it will have you input something the add what you inputed in the f string.