# In Python how do I make text in a console that can be edited after it is printed?

Tags: python

I was wondering if there was any way to make text that the user can edit after it is printed. For example, if I were to use `input = input("thingo: ")`, it prints "thingo: " and then the user can type and delete in after "thingo: " is printed.

I was wondering if I could achieve a similar effect with already existing text. Imagine that the user had typed a paragraph or something after the "thingo: ". The user could type more to the paragraph, or remove text from the already existing paragraph. However in what I want, the user did not actually type the original paragraph, it was printed by the code into the console.

Thanks for any help you can give!

Comment: Yes. [curses](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/curses.html). And that is not a minor expletive. Actually, maybe it is.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Edit text using Python and curses Textbox widget?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4581441/edit-text-using-python-and-curses-textbox-widget)